# How to create tab buttons that links to its respective tab when creating a form in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a form in HTML that will have multiple tabs. I have a previous and next button to go through all the tabs as if they were pages. I also have circles at the bottom of the tab to inform the user what tab they are actively on and which tabs are next and which tabs were before. I would like each tab to be a link that when the user clicks on it will link them to it's respective tab. For example if I click on the tab circle labeled A it will bring me to the A tab. I tried using and internal link with anchor tags but that did not seem to work. Any idea? Thank you.

```js
 //Form Tabs
      var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
      showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

      function showTab(n) {
        // This function will display the specified tab of the form ...
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        x[n].style.display = "block";

        // ... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
      /*  if (n == 0) {
          document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
        }
        if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
          document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
        }*/
        // ... and run a function that displays the correct step indicator:

        //Form 1 displays only Next button, Previous button is disabled.
        if (n == 0) {
           document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
         } else {
           document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
         }
         //Form 5 displays only Previous button, Next button is disabled.
         if (n == 1) {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").style.display = "none";
          } else {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").style.display = "inline";
          }
        fixStepIndicator(n)
          }

      function nextPrev(n) {
        // This function will figure out which tab to display
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
        if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
        // Hide the current tab:
        x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
        // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
        currentTab = currentTab + n;
        // if you have reached the end of the form... :
        if (currentTab >= x.length) {
          //...the form gets submitted:
          document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
          return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
        showTab(currentTab);
      }

      function validateForm() {
        // This function deals with validation of the form fields
        var x, y, i, valid = true;
        x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
        // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
        for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
          // If a field is empty...
          if (y[i].value == "") {
            // add an "invalid" class to the field:
            y[i].className += " invalid";
            // and set the current valid status to false:
            valid = false;
          }
        }
        // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
        if (valid) {
          document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
        }
        return valid; // return the valid status
      }

      function fixStepIndicator(n) {
        // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
        var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        //... and adds the "active" class to the current step:
        x[n].className += " active";
      }
```

```css
   /* Style for Select */
            /* Style the form */
            #regForm {
              background-color: #e9e9e9;
              margin: 20px auto;
              width: 70%;
              min-width: 300px;
            }
    /* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
            .step {
              height: 15px;
              width: 15px;
              margin: 0 2px;
              background-color: #b8cce4;
              border: none;
              border-radius: 50%;
              display: inline-block;
              opacity: 0.5;
            }

            /* Mark the active step: */
            .step.active {
              opacity: 1;
            }

            /* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
            .step.finish {
              background-color: #b8cce4;
            }

            /*Used for blue background headings */
            tr.blueHead {
              background-color: #b8cce4;
            }
```

```html
   

 

<div id="regForm">
          <div class="tab">
            <h1>Tab A</h1>
          </div>

          <div class="tab">
          <h1>Tab B</h1>
          </div>

          <div style="float:right;">
           <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
           <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button></div>
          </div>

          <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
            <span class="step">A</span>
            <span class="step">B</span>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** I've made my own code, use it as a guide, use your circles and stuff. :)

**EDIT 2:** Made a cooler scale-up effect for you in the jsfiddle link.

Create toggable tabs

```
<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'First')">First Tab</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Second')">Second Tab</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Third')">Third tab</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="First" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>First tab</h3>
  <p>Hi there! I'm the first tab.</p>
</div>

<div id="Second" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Second tab</h3>
  <p>I'm the second tab.</p>
</div>

<div id="Third" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Third tab</h3>
  <p>I'm the third tab.</p>
</div>
```

Add some CSS so it can look a bit cooler

```
header {
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
.tabcontent {
  animation: fadeEffect 1s; /* Fading effect takes 1 second */
}

/* Go from zero to full opacity */
@keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

Give them some js

```
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

[Click me to see my example working](https://jsfiddle.net/rick95/t4z7hc2k/)